# Windows 7 says that I have three displays connected, however I only have two

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I recently connected a second monitor to my computer but it is saying that I have got  3 connected when I obviously don't.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I'd like to get rid of the third monitor which doesn't exist.

Comment: ok - tell us what graphics card and motherboard processor combo you have.  It may be that the VGA output is enabled by default and cannot be easily turned off.

Comment: I've got a ASUS Nvidia GeForce GTX 770 gpu and a MSI Z87-G43 motherboard.

Answer (score 3):

While having the middle display selected, change the multiple display option to disconnect.